# Error While Booting GRML

Tags: linux, live-usb, grml

I'm dropped the 32-bit GRML ISO onto a 1GB thumb drive with the usual command:

```
dd if=grml_2010.12.iso of=/dev/USB_STICK
```

(of course, with the correct device).  But, when I try to boot from it, it produces this error:

```
0AAD Loading ...bad magic error
...bad magic
```

And then proceeds to restart.  What would cause that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posing this answer because this is the first Google hit when you search for the error.

In my case, what caused the error was "wrong architecture" - I tried to boot a 64bit system on a 32bit computer.